# Google Analytics Tracking Code Mobile

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-analytics

I don't understand why there are so many URLs, and what they are used for...

Under -- Admin --> Profiles Tab --> Profile Settings
there is a tab for a website URL

Under Admin --> Property Settings
there is a tab for another URL

Then in the Java code you can input another URL with the method
tracker.trackPageView("/whateverYouWant.com");

I noticed that tracker.trackPageView sets up where the analytics is set up
What are these for? I can't find good documentation on this.

Keep in mind this is different than a normal analytics for a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics for mobile devices is a low-effort port of their existing website-oriented infrastructure.  You need to phrase all of your app's events as website-like operations.  And you need to configure the analytics infrastructure as if your app was a website.

This blog post has some more suggestions for how to map android/mobile state to the webbish analytics state:
http://bitiotic.com/blog/2012/05/20/mapping-google-analytics-to-an-android-game-with-libgdx/

Comment: that makes sense, i don't think the link helps me tho. I now understand that even a mobile app has to work like a website structure, but how do they interweave with each other? the non java URL's im so confused about

Comment: The URLs in the Admin interface are just labels, you can mostly ignore them.  The URLs in the trackPageView() calls should all be of the form "/something/something" (no hostname).  Read the section "Mapping apps to GA" in that blog, I think it will help you.  Also, I suggest setting up GA on a regular website if you can, just to see what things look like in the UI.